# Why can't I ask this question?

Tags: support

I am trying to add a question on StackOverflow, but the system is rejecting it with no error explanation...I have tried re-wording it including changing the title, but no luck.

So is my account suspended - I can't see anything like that on my profile?

Or is it being rejected by rules on the site for something wrong with it. I don't think there are any true duplicates?

Here is the question I was trying to add:

> In our table we have a field with length of nvarchar(70) which is used to store multiple values that can be queried using SUBSTRING. There are already 54 characters in the field including the final quote.
>
> The Start and end characters of the field are always a single quote.
>
> I need to update the field, adding up to 3 characters from another reference table.
>   I tried the below, but it is missing of the last character when the number is greater than 9.
>
> ```
> update Hermes_Rep.dbo.ActData
> set spare6= LEFT(Spare6+SPACE(57),57) + ''''
> FROM Hermes_Rep.dbo.ACTdata 
> LEFT JOIN KFILDTO_YARPF YAR ON ACTdata.ACNo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS= YAR.YARCUS COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
> where DataDate='2014-09-16'
> ```
>
> For example, if the data I am adding is `N9'` it works, but if the data is `N11` it only puts in `N1`
>   So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you say no error explanation: what is the behavior? Are you clicking the "Post Your Question" and nothing happens?

Comment: hi David, I get the red box `an error occurred submitting your question`

Comment: is it possible that today is the wrong day to be using IE 8?

Comment: Every day is the wrong day to be using IE 8...

Comment: BTW, I was using the `SQL`, `sql-server-2008-r2` and `TSQL` tags

Comment: I'll try and add the question uising Google Chrome, in case it really is an IE problem (which is quite possible)

Comment: @Philip technically [IE8 isn't supported anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).  Only the current and 1-2 previous versions are supported.

Comment: same issue on Google Chrome, so for once it's not IE.

Comment: You are being blocked by a local firewall or router. Try posting without including SQL statements, or better yet, use the `https` encrypted version of Stack Overflow when posting. And ask your local network administrators to dial back the paranoia on the SQL injection attack detection.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: using the secure site `https` worked. Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your account is not blocked or suspended.

If it was you'd get a different error message if you tried to post a question.

There are quality filters but they should only kick in if you're posting a load of code with no explanatory text for example, which is not the case here.

The first thing I'd do is close and reopen the browser and possible clear the cache just to make sure you have all the most up-to-date files and scripts then try again. If you still can't post take a screenshot of the error and add it to your question. It might give someone a clue as to what's going on.

As far as I know all errors are logged, so a dev or community manager might be able to dig deeper and see what the problem is.

Or, of course, it could be that your request is being blocked by your local firewall/router.

Comment: thanks but it was solved by usng the secure encrypted version of So as suggested by Martin in his comment.